# Closest equivalent of "bless you" for coughing

Tags: idioms, synonyms

There is [no English equivalent of "bless you" for coughing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304248/is-there-an-equivalent-of-bless-you-for-coughing/375232#375232).

Some friends and I would like to use a phrase for "bless you" for coughing amongst ourselves. What would an appropriate word, phrase, or idiom be that has sensible linguistic roots?

Comment: We don't really tend to say anything after someone coughs. If it's a recurring cough, then it is natural to ask someone if they are "okay"/"alright", and offer them a glass of water.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but isn't really suitable for this format because there is no way to judge whether one answer is better than another objectively. You might bring it up in [chat] and see what the folks there think.

Comment: There is probably enough cultural differences among English speaking countries to warrant an answer.

Comment: How about “Would you be so kind as to put on a mask?” Or call the cops. Six of one.

Comment: "Plague!" "Bring out your dead!" You should think what you want to communicate, whether it's to wish good health, to reference something supernatural (there are various dubious theories that "bless you" could be associated with evil spirits leaving the body or good spirits that needed to be kept in), or something more practical. Something like "bless you" will only make sense if you believe in a particular type of God. But it seems off topic for here.

Comment: We do have "Thanks for sharing"—but that seems inappropriate in this context. A friend of mine habitually responds to a fit of coughing by politely and sympathetically (yet humorously) inquiring "A bit of catarrh?" I would love to see that (not catarrh) catch on.

Answer (score 1):

"Are you okay?" is an acceptable reaction.